# Export Custom Views (Administrative Events) From The Event Viewer C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, events, logging

I'm having a hard time finding the answer to this problem. I've been looking around, But never seemed to have come across a solution.

Okay all I'm trying to export are the .evtx files from the event viewer pragmatically using C#. I managed to successfully do this for the following:

- Application
- System
- Security

But I'm also looking to grab the "Administrative Events". And even though  I'm using the same code as shown below to grab the other three, it doesn't work.

This code works as expected and exports the Event Logs to the specified directory:

```
session.ExportLogAndMessages("Application", PathType.LogName, "*", logPaths[(int)EVENTLOGS.APPLICATION]);
session.ExportLogAndMessages("System", PathType.LogName, "*", logPaths[(int)EVENTLOGS.SYSTEM]);
session.ExportLogAndMessages("Security", PathType.LogName, "*", logPaths[(int)EVENTLOGS.SECURITY]);
```

Where as in this section when I try to grab the "Administrative Events" It gives me the this error: "TheSpecified channel could not be found. Check channel configuration"

```
session.ExportLogAndMessages("Administrative Events", PathType.LogName, "*", logPaths[(int)EVENTLOGS.ADMINISTRATIVE]);
```

Any ideas? is there a different API call that should be used when trying to grab custom views? I thank you all kindly in advanced for your kind and prompt response.

Comment: Are you sure it can be exported?  When I look at EventViewer, the others show up as logs, but "Adminstrative Events" shows up as a custom view.  Sounds like that is a special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can export Administrative Events using that method, as it is a custom view across multiple logs.  I think you would have to use the EventLogQuery class to simulate the same filter and try to export those results.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast. I'll go ahead and give it a try. I'll keep you updated on my status. Thanks!

Comment: http://blog-mstechnology.blogspot.com/2009/08/filter-eventlog-entries-thru-c-code.html  makes it look like WMI objects might be a btter way to go.